# Object of type Logo is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization

I'm trying to build django rest api which will get images from front part and also serve it via REST APi, the problem is that eventho I'm able to post data to django via PostMan, still I get error Object of type 'Logo' is not JSON serializable. Data is already in database but I would like to fix this issue but dont know where to start, tried to change Response to JsonResponse but it brought no effect

Model

```
class Logo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    preview = models.ImageField()
    thumb = models.ImageField()
    thumbL = models.ImageField()
    dataL = models.TextField(blank=False)
    thumbS = models.ImageField()
    dataS = models.TextField()
    posL = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    posS = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Serialization:

```
class LogoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    posL = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    posS = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    dataL = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    dataS = serializers.CharField(required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Logo
        fields = ('__all__')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            return Logo.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

and View:

```
class LogoViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Logo.objects.all()
        serializer = LogoSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = LogoSerializer(data=request.data)


        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.validated_data['posL'] = positionL
            serializer.validated_data['posS'] = positionS
            bg = serializer.save()
            return Response(bg, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:
            bg = serializer.errors
            return Response(bg, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/#pulling-it-all-together) you should use `serializer.data` instead of `bg` in your response.

So `return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)`

The reason for this is because you are passing a Django model instance, which doesn't really have the fields in raw JSON serializable format, but rather a more complex object with field ins the format of `CharFields`, `ImageFields`, as well as a meta property that defines some of the model's properties like database table, etc.

Comment: Ah I understand, omg and solution was as easy... anyway now it works with no errors:) Thanks mate!